# Работа с потоками delphi

Tags: delphi

Ставил вот такой эксперимент

```
type
  TTH = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
...............................
  private
  { Private declarations }
    Threads: array of TTH;
  public
  { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  i:integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TTH.Execute;
var
```

`//   Threads: array of TTH;  (эксперементировал тут, почему в процедуре Execute оно не видит Threads если его не прописать в var этой процедуре?)
    begin
   //   SetLength(Threads, 10);
      while i <> 4 do
      begin
        form1.memo2.Lines.Add('Строка: '+inttostr(i));
        form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);
        //sleep(RandomRange(25000, 3000));
        Sleep(10000);
        form1.memo2.Lines.Add('olololo');
        form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);
       end;
    end;`

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(Threads, 10);
  for i := 0 to 4 do
  begin
```

`sleep(1000);  без этих строк данный цикл настолько быстро даёт результат i = 4 что в процедуре execute ничего не успевает выполниться, т.е. пока поток запустится в execute, i уже равно 4 и тот цикл пропускается, если поставить паузу тут и посмотреть как потоки запускаются по очереди, то видно, что когда i = 4, а поток в процедуре execute выполняет команду sleep, то после выхода из сна, он не выполняет следующее действие, а просто завершается, такое ощущение что после sleep(), цикл проверяет условие, т.е. смотрит чему равно i и если i <> 4 выполняет дальше команды в цикле, почему?)))
      Application.ProcessMessages;
        Threads[i] := TTH.Create(true);
        //Threads[i].FreeOnTerminate := True;
        Threads[i].Resume;
      end;
    end;`

Надеюсь понятно, что я делал)

Суть такая: в процедуре `execute` после `sleep()` не выполняется `form1.memo1.Lines.Add('olololo');`, потоки просто уничтожаются, потому что цикл достиг своего условия. Мне интересно, почему оно так делает? Я знаю что для VCL нужно делать `Synchronize();`, но посчитал ради эксперимента и так можно.

Кто нибудь дайте ссылочки на книги именно про потоки, где про них всё всё написано. Весь инет перерыл, гугл уже боится меня, везде одно и тоже создание одного потока либо битва двух потоков.

```
/**************************************/
```

Не хочет оно выполнять  после `sleep` следующую команду, просто уничтожаются потоки и всё.

Может кто скинет название книг в которых подробно написано про потоки и есть примеры?

Comment: С begin-end всё в порядке? В SetLength два begin и один end.

Comment: Поправьте код в вопросе, на компилируемый.

Comment: Запустил ваш код (с правками begin/end из уточнения) - все нормально работает.

Comment: Использование общей глобальной переменной `i` в потоках .. как-бы помягче сказать .. вообщем не надо так делать.

Comment: По ссылке демонстрационная учебная программа http://blog.ivru.net/?id=198 с простыми и понятными по коду листингами использования потоков(TThread) в Delphi 6.
В том числе где нужно применяется Synchronize(используется для устранения конфликтов когда 2 потока попытаются изменить свойство например одного визуального объекта на форме), а так же показана работа Terminated(прерывание выполнения потока например из процедур основной программы).

Answer (score 1):

Ну а что вы хотели получить, если есть глобальная переменная `i`, которая используется как на форме (при создании каждого потока - `i` увеличивается на 1), так и в самих потоках (проверка, создались все потоки или нет - если все создались, тогда ничего не делать). Это на самом деле игра в рулетку, то потоки успели создастся то нет и все отработало один раз или несколько.

По коду:

1. Так все таки `TTH` или `TmyTH`? (Будем считать что опечатка)
2. Глобальная переменная которая используется как в коде формы так и в потоке.
3. Переменная `Threads` больше нигде не используется
4. Создается 4 элемента массива, а перебор идет по 5-ти. (Проверку можно включить так: `Project->Options->Compiling->Runtime error-> Range checking`)
5. Также можете вывести ThreadID потока - тогда будет ясно с какого потока пришло сообщение.
6. `Synchronize` обязательно.

   ```
   type
     TTH = class(TThread)       <---- 1.
     protected
       procedure Execute; override;
     end;

     TForm1 = class(TForm)
     ...
     private
       Threads: array of TmyTH;  <---- 1.
     end;

   var
     Form1: TForm1;
     i: integer;     <---- 2.

   implementation

   procedure TmyTH.Execute;
   var
     Threads: array of TTH;  <---- 1. 3.
   begin
     SetLength(Threads, 10); <---- 3.

     while i <> 4 do
     begin
       form1.memo2.Lines.Add('Строка: '+inttostr(i));  <---- 6.
       form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);  <---- 6.
       //  sleep(RandomRange(25000, 3000));
       Sleep(10000);
       form1.memo2.Lines.Add('olololo');  <---- 6.
       form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);  <---- 6.
     end;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     SetLength(Threads, 4);   <---- 4.

     for i := 0 to 4 do       <---- 4. 
     begin
        Threads[i] := TmyTH.Create(true);
       // Threads[i].FreeOnTerminate := True;   
       Threads[i].Resume;
     end;
   end;
   ```

Comment: +1, я бы добавил еще пункт-предупреждение, про то что Form1 это тоже глобальная переменная к которой нехорошо обращаться из потоков.

Answer (score -1):

Возможная причина такого поведения программы sleep(...) вне цикла while i <> 4 do

while i <> 4 do **BEGIN**

Answer (score -1):

Сори хотел сильно спать и накосячил тут с бегинами, вот код

```
type
  TTH = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    Threads: array of TmyTH;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  i:integer;

implementation

procedure TmyTH.Execute;
var
  Threads: array of TTH;
begin
  SetLength(Threads, 10);

  while i <> 4 do
  begin

    form1.memo2.Lines.Add('Строка: '+inttostr(i));
    form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);
    //  sleep(RandomRange(25000, 3000));
    Sleep(10000);
    form1.memo2.Lines.Add('olololo');
    form1.Label3.Caption:='Строк в мемо '+inttostr(form1.Memo2.Lines.Count);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(Threads, 4);

  for i := 0 to 4 do 
  begin
    Threads[i] := TmyTH.Create(true);
    // Threads[i].FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Threads[i].Resume;
  end;
end;
```

После выхода из sleep в цикле процедуры Execute оно игнорирует строку `form1.memo2.Lines.Add('olololo');` такое впечатление, что после sleep цикл проверяет *i* видит, что оно равно 4 и выходит из цикла. Я смотрел и видел как в "мониторинге ресурсов" программа создаёт потоки (кол-во какое я укажу в цикле запуска потоков) вижу, что доходит до sleep, ставил разное время, и вижу, как по истечению времени sleep потоки уничтожаются

**//*****************************//**

Я не знал что и как тут надо добавлять и почему то решил что можно добавить сюда "Новый ответ"

Нашёл новые **внятные** уроки, завтра скорее всего будет рабочий код)

Comment: В ответе должен быть "ответ". Дополнения вопроса делайте правками вопроса